# FormGroup in FormArray

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular4-forms, formgroups

I am using FormArray then include Form Group in that but not be able to access  in html through *ngFor. I tried many things but not works. here is typescript code.

```
  private readonly TRAINING_FORM: any = new FormGroup({
    // new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    codeSchool: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    adressStreetInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    adressCityInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    adressStateInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    adressZipInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    phoneInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    isProgramInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    faxInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    noteInst: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    // trainingExtraInformation: new FormArray([])
  });


 ngOnInit() {
    this.loadForm();
  }

  loadForm() {
    const trainingArray = new FormArray([this.TRAINING_FORM]);
    const totalInst = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.trainingForm = new FormGroup({
      totalInst,
      trainingArray
    });
  }
```

and here it is html ngFor.

```
 <div formArrayName="trainingArray">
          <div *ngFor="let training of trainings; index as idx" formArrayName="idx">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Training institution/hospital name
                  <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No abbreviations, please"
                         [formControlName]="idx">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you use ngFor here

```
<div *ngFor="let training of trainings; index as idx" formArrayName="idx">
```

But where do you want to access/show each "training"-object? There's no part in the template where you try this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot give value to the FormGroup!!

```
loadForm() {
    const trainingArray = new FormArray([this.TRAINING_FORM]);
    const totalInst = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.trainingForm = new FormGroup({
      totalInst:totalInst, //<--give value to TotalInst
      trainingArray:trainingArray  //<---idem
    });
}
```